# Reloading div to reload XML

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, timer

Inside of *div#weather*, I have some PHP that is calling an Google's weather XML. It works great, except that it gets stale. I'd like to reload the div every 600000 milliseconds to get fresh XML.

I was going down the path of a javascript timer, but that seems to require an external URL.

If I need to have the PHP in an external file, it's no big deal, just not ideal.

```
<div id="weather">
<?php
    $URL = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=60618";
    $dataInISO = file_get_contents($URL);
    $dataInUTF = mb_convert_encoding($dataInISO, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2");
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($dataInUTF);
    $current = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions");
?>
    <div class="weather-<?php $weather =  $current[0]->condition['data']; $weatherclass = str_replace(' ','-',$weather); $weatherclass = strtolower($weatherclass); echo $weatherclass; ?>">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="temp"><?= $current[0]->temp_f['data'] ?>&deg;</div>
    <div id="condition"><?= $current[0]->condition['data'] ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you make a `weather.php` file that you can query via AJAX?

Comment: Other than what Blender said, the only thing I can see is putting a `meta refresh` on the page. Go for AJAX, that's obviously the solution.

Comment: @Blender an external weather.php is fine, I was just hoping to keep it simpler in one file. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Blender, if you want to make that an answer, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your single file, you can use ajax to call itself and then just grab the html inside `<div id="weather">` to replace your current div.

```
$.get('your current page.php', function(data){
   var a = $(data);
   var weather = $(a).find('#weather').html();
   $('#weather').html(weather);
});
```